How to make Docusaurus navbar dropdown label dynamic (like it is for the versions and locale dropdowns)?
Docusaurus supports navbar dropdowns, but for these you have to set a static label. For example, you can create a dropdown labeled "Options" with item values "One" and "Two". But if you select one of the item, the label stays the same — because it's static.
But the natively supported navbar docs version dropdown and navbar locale dropdown behave differently. Their labels are dynamic, based on the item selected. For example, if you select "v1" in the version dropdown, the label of the dropdown changes to "v1".
I'd like to create a custom navbar dropdown — not for versions or locale — that has a dynamic label (like the versions and locale dropdowns). How can I do this?
Thanks!
